# How to track who hits the slash-command in slack?

Tags: jenkins, slack

I have created `slash command` (via add integration method) in slack for deploying in Jenkins.(hitting the slash-command will trigger the Jenkins build)

It was working fine; and notification was sent to a channel that too also was fine.

But there is no way to track who hit the `slash-command` in slack

**How to track the users who hit the `slash-command`**

Comment: How do you want to track this? The slash command sends a HTTP post with a `user_name` attribute. Do you have access to the slash-command request? Here are all the attributes the command will send: https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#triggering_a_command

Comment: I'm not using slack enterprise; it's a free version. are we need enterprise for this to achieve? How to get access to slash-command request? actual need : when i hit a /deploy command in slack it will deploy the plan in Jenkins and result was published in the slack #channel. it was working fine. but how to identify who issues the command(who hits the command in that channel) once the hit is made i need to know person "x" hits the /deploy command